# How can I find the Linear Map given the Image?

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, linear-transformations

Find the linear map $F : \mathbb{R}^3 → \mathbb{R}^3$ whose image is a subspace with the basis: $\{(1,2,3),(4,5,6)\}$.

Comment: Is that a *basis* of the image? Notice the image of a linear transformation is always a subspace. In any case, plenty of different linear transformations share the same image, so your answer (if that is the question) will most certainly not be unique.

Comment: Yes, is the basis

Comment: You can't. There are many of them, even if these vectors are the images of two vectors of the canonical basis.

Comment: Building off of @Fimpellizieri's comment: one way to see that there are infinitely many such maps is to note that $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5,6)$ define a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Take a vector normal to this plane, and then compose $F$ with a rotation about this vector by $\theta$ radians. Then $R_\theta\circ F$ is a linear map with the same image, but there are uncountably many such maps (since we can take $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$).

If you just need *one* example of such a map, use the obvious one: define $F(e_1)=(1,2,3)$, $F(e_2)=(4,5,6)$, and $F(e_3)=(0,0,0)$ and extend linearly.

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out in the comments, there are many such maps. So I'm guessing you just want to find one of them.

A linear map is determined by its action on a basis, e.g. the standard basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$. So what would be a good choice for $F(e_1),F(e_2)$, and $F(e_3)$?